# B2C Authenticate User In Web Api

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-6.0, azure-ad-b2c

I have a web app where a user logs in through b2c and have certain claims set once they're logged in. Now, I also need to call an api with javascript when a user clicks a button. So that's all fine but, here's my question:

How would I get the user's claims in the api?

My api and client side web app are both in asp.net core.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what identity provider(within your app)are you using ?

Comment: thanks for the fast reply :] I'm using azure b2c.

Comment: does this help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-api?tabs=csharpclient

Comment: I only have a program.cs file since i'm using dotnet core

Comment: Then you will need to create Startup.cs and appsettings.json, why dont you use the new project and select the template so you get all the files you are missing now?

Comment: In .NET 6 Microsoft has removed the Startup.cs class.

Comment: i guess you are on a minimal web api ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: yes. i am using that.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you may refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-web-app-with-api?tabs=visual-studio) or this [official sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C) to check if it met your requirement.

For the api, it will return user information which is signed in the app.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Todo> Get()
{
     string owner = User.Identity.Name;
     return TodoStore.Values.Where(x => x.Owner == owner);
}
```

[image: Get user information from User.Identity]